# Retrieve current grade level of a student via Google Classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

Is there a method to retrieve the current grade level of a student via the Google Classroom API? (e.g student is in grade 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. If you will check the [Classroom API REST Resources](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest).
[courses.students.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/get) method will return an instance of [Student](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students#Student) which contains the following fields:

[image]

---

Wherein, [UserProfile](http://UserProfile) object only contains the following information: `id`, `name`, `emailAddress`, `photoUrl`, `permissions` and `verifiedTeacher`

Comment: That is what I thought looking at the documentation, thanks for confirming Ron.